# MongoDB: Check for missing documents using a model tree structures with an array of ancestors

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm using a model tree structures with an array of ancestors and I need to check if any document is missing.

```
{
    "_id" : "GbxvxMdQ9rv8p6b8M",
    "type" : "article",
    "ancestors" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : "mtmTBW8nA4YoCevf4",
    "parent" : "GbxvxMdQ9rv8p6b8M",
    "ancestors" : [
        "GbxvxMdQ9rv8p6b8M"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "J5Dg4fB5Kmdbi8mwj",
    "parent" : "mtmTBW8nA4YoCevf4",
    "ancestors" : [
        "GbxvxMdQ9rv8p6b8M",
        "mtmTBW8nA4YoCevf4"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "tYmH8fQeTLpe4wxi7",
    "refType" : "reference",
    "parent" : "J5Dg4fB5Kmdbi8mwj",
    "ancestors" : [
        "GbxvxMdQ9rv8p6b8M",
        "mtmTBW8nA4YoCevf4",
        "J5Dg4fB5Kmdbi8mwj"
    ]
}
```

My attempt would be to check each ancestors id if it is existing. If this fails, this document is missing and the data structure is corrupted.

```
let ancestors;

Collection.find().forEach(r => {
    if (r.ancestors) {
        r.ancestors.forEach(a => {
            if (!Collection.findOne(a))
                missing.push(r._id);
        });
    }
});
```

But doing it like this will need MANY db calls. Is it possible to optimize this?
Maybe I could get an array with all unique ancestor ids first and check if these documents are existing within one db call??

Comment: Perhaps in MongoDB 3.4

Answer (score 0):

First take out all distinct ancesstors from your collections.

```
var allAncesstorIds = db.<collectionName>.distinct("ancestors");
```

Then check if any of the ancesstor IDs are not in the collection.

```
var cursor = db.<collectionName>.find({_id : {$nin : allAncesstorIds}}, {_id : 1})
```

Iterate the cursor and insert all missing docs in a collection.

```
cursor.forEach(function (missingDocId) {
  db.missing.insert(missingDocId);
});
```

Comment: This won't work as $nin won't give me documents which are not existing. I need to check which id of allAncesstorIds is not existing at all. It works if I do `findOne()` for each element of allAncesstorIds, but I would lead to many many queries...

Comment: This would give you IDs which are present in the ancesstor field of one or more documents but a document with that ID doesn't exist. Isn't this what you want? Can you give an example?